# Extract data from public Google Calendar

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, google-calendar-api

I am trying to grab the event data from the google calendar [here](https://www.phoenixcsd.org/Calendar). I am having trouble understanding where to find the calendar id in order to use the api, so the example provided on the api hasnt helped me yet. The only link I can find skimming through the html is this:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showTz=0&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=phoenixcsd.net_n9i5susso9gnl3cur7vsh8gr6o@group.calendar.google.com&color=%2342104A&src=phoenixcsd.net_ivcl5r5lc9bj0082lpl5ssr3h8@group.calendar.google.com&color=%238C500B&src=phoenixcsd.net_gu6bfruuj9lhbuq9tkrsuahkhc@group.calendar.google.com&color=%2329527A&src=phoenixcsd.net_klr8hsblptggl9qluiidj47k90@group.calendar.google.com&color=%230F4B38&src=en.usa%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=phoenixcsd.net_4d5gf78r3ili7i499jpoev0m18@group.calendar.google.com&color=%2328754E&src=phoenixcsd.net_9ispj3bk9tlrlsg2sq46ika564@group.calendar.google.com&color=%235F6B02&src=phoenixcsd.net_peaa7tsif8bdk54fs61at335ks@group.calendar.google.com&color=%23AB8B00&ctz=America/New_York

as far as I can tell, one of the strings following the src= is supposed to be the calendar id, but ive tried them all. One example is: phoenixcsd.net_peaa7tsif8bdk54fs61at335ks@group.calendar.google.com

I tried verifying with [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get), but they all gave errors.

I believe I am missing something simple, so how do I

1. Access the google calendar in my code
2. Use the api to extract all events (or at least events between two dates) from the calendar
3. Store the events in a dataframe

thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

This [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) should answer the first two questions. You use [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to fetch all the events from your calendar.

Comment: I followed that Quickstart but I dont know how to access the calendar or where to find the auth/calendar id. Digging further, the Oauth 2.0 scopes says this: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' to edit or 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly' to read, but what goes in auth?